# Python logging to consecutive files

Tags: python, logging

Basically, I want to conduct test 1 and log results into into log file 1, test 2 logging results into log file 2, test3 into log file 3, etc. I've read the basic [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) and tried several examples and tutorials but I'm stuck. I'm trying to close the handler, then delete and recreate the logger. However, I find that the old handler(s) remain active after I have closed them down. Meaning that log file 1 contains the results from test1, test2, test3; log file 2 contains the results from test2, test3, etc.

Here's my function for setting up the logger (modified from [this example](http://rlabs.wordpress.com/2009/04/09/python-closing-logging-file-getlogger/): )

```
import logging, logging.handlers, os, sys

def createLogger(self, fileName):
''' Create logger (and its' folder if it does not exist), return logger and its' path '''
# Check whether logger already set up
if self.logger is not None:
    # Logger already exists, remove it
    print >> sys.stderr, "Logger already exists, removing it.."
    self.hdl.close()
    del self.logger, self.hdl
    (self.logger, self.hdl) = (None, None)
else:
    print >> sys.stderr, "No logger existed before"

self.logger = logging.getLogger('testLogger')
# Strip filename from fileName
filePathTuple = os.path.split(fileName)
filePath = filePathTuple[0] + '/'
# Create directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(filePath):
    os.makedirs( filePath )
# Create and set handler, formatter
self.hdl = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileName, maxBytes=2097152, backupCount=5)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
self.hdl.setFormatter(formatter)
self.logger.addHandler(self.hdl)
self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
return filePath
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I just feel like I'm digging myself deeper into a  hole of ignorance trying to understand handlers.

--Edit: Working solution --

Substitute the initial if/else statement with this:

```
def createLogger(self, fileName):
    # Check whether logger already set up
    if self.logger is not None:
        # Logger already exists, remove it
        print >> sys.stderr, "Logger already exists, removing it.."
        self.logger.removeHandler(self.hdl)
        self.hdl.close()
    else:
        print >> sys.stderr, "No logger existed before"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `addHandler` and `removeHandler` methods on the logger to add/remove handlers specific to each test, then close the handler once it's been removed. Assuming you're testing using unittest:

```
# test_module.py
import logging, unittest
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        handler = ...
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        try:
            # body of test
        finally:
            logger.removeHandler(handler)
            handler.close()
```

You can adapt the above to a different test runner, if needed. You may want to open file handlers using the append mode ('a'), otherwise tests which run later will overwrite the output from tests which run earlier.

Comment: Many thanks, that answered my query beautifully. I've amended my question to include my fix. (I'm passing a unique fileName argument to the function each time it's called).